# Using firebug, where are the js errors shown?

Tags: javascript, debugging, firebug

using firebug, where are the js errors shown when the page renders? (if you have any good js debugging links w/firebug send them my way please!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Javascript errors will be listed in the Console of Firebug.

You can also set Firebug to break on all errors, which is helpful for detecting why the error was thrown.

Answer (score 3):

As you are asking for some links:

1. [Firebug Tutorial - Logging, Profiling and CommandLine (Part I)](http://michaelsync.net/2007/09/09/firebug-tutorial-logging-profiling-and-commandline-part-i)
2. [Firebug Tutorial - Logging,
   Profiling and CommandLine (Part II)](http://michaelsync.net/2007/09/10/firebug-tutorial-logging-profiling-and-commandline-part-ii)
3. [Firebug Tutorial - Using Commandline API in Firebug](http://michaelsync.net/2007/09/15/firebug-tutorial-commandline-api)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to enable the Script panel for whatever site you're looking at.  Once you do that, it will show the "Watch", "Stack" and "Breakpoints" tabs in the lower pane under the Script tab.